# Using PowerShell to list defaults Computer-wide Launch and Activation Permissions for all users

Tags: windows, powershell, security, dcom

Environment:

- Windows 10
- PowerShell 5.1

Problem:
I need some kind of script that list users and it's permission in the COM Security object computer wide ("Launch and Activation Permission" -- Default permission)

In GUI-way I can do it by running "DCOMCNFG --> Component Services --> Computers --> My Computer --> (right click) --> Permissions --> "COM Security" --> "Edit default..." (in the "Launch and Activation Permissions" sections in the bottom of window).

So what I actually need it checks that some users have "Local Launch, Remote Launch, Local Activation, and Remote Activation" permission.
I try to automate it.

---

Update: at the moment I start using DComPerm.exe

```
DComPerm.exe -dl list
```

If you know a better way -- please share knowledge!

I try using

- DComPerm.exe -- compiled, exactly do what I need. Work for me now.
  Sources were taken from here: [DComPermEx](https://github.com/albertony/dcompermex)
- RegKey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Ole -- That key have some information, plan to try to decode it
- `Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_DCOMApplicationAccessAllowedSetting" | Select-String -Pattern "S-###-MY-USER-SUID"` -- not completely understand what to lookout.
- [This blog proposes a decision to add user in DCOM Launch and Activation permission](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/using-powershell-to-modify-dcom-launch-activation-settings/) -- can it be used for reading access-list?

So again: how to list access levels for all users in default computer-wide DCOM Security object "Launch and Activation" with PowerShell
Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: DComPermEx was exactly what I needed. Here is the command to enables remote and local launch and activation permissions at the machine level (replace with your domain and identity/group): `DComPermEx.exe -ml set "[domain]\[identity_or_group]" permit level:l,r`